# How to call a path stored in string variable without eval in link_to for rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

The index path of quotes is stored and retrieved from var `JobshopRfqx.quote_index_pat`h. Here is how the variable is defined:

```
JobshopRfqx.quote_index_path = 'jobshop_quotex.quotes_path(:rfq_id => r.id)'
```

Here is the link_to which works (eval):

```
<%= link_to t('Quotes'), eval(JobshopRfqx.quote_index_path.to_s) %>
```

Here is the link_to which did not work:

```
<%= link_to t('Quotes'), Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send(JobshopRfqx.quote_index_path.to_s) %>
```

Here is the error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `jobshop_quotex.quotes_path(:rfq_id => r.id)' for #<Module:0x42d5c90>
```

Without eval, what's the right way to call a string path?

Comment: Why are you storing this in a String? Why not `JobshopRfqx.quote_index_path = jobshop_quotex.quotes_path(:rfq_id => r.id)`

Comment: We can only store the path in a string var. otherwise the the path will be evaluated at the time when it is loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `send` you have to pass the name of the method separately from the arguments.  You'd have to do something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send('jobshop_quotex.quotes_path', :rfq_id => r.id)
```

But, I don't think that's going to do what you want though.  I really don't understand why you'd want to do this...

Comment: There are many rails engines in the app and we don't want to hardcode engine used in one app. By moving the name to the initializer file we can get away with the code changing when another engine is mounted.

Comment: Ah, I see.  In that case what I suggested may work, if you just store the name of the method, but then still pass arguments directly.  Not sure if that will work for you or not.

Comment: if there are more than one params, just add more hash as var?

Comment: Yeah, you can just add more params.  When you call `send` the first arg should be the name of the method that you want to call.  Everything after that should be the normal arguments that you'd pass to that method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're doing this, but the correct thing to do here is to use a Proc.

```
JobshopRfqx.quote_index_path = Proc.new { |js_quotex, r| js_quotex.quotes_path(:rfq_id => r.id) }
```

Then you can get the path you are looking for by calling:

```
link_to t('Quotes'), JobshopRfqx.quote_index_path.call(jobshop_quotex, r)
```

I'm like 90% sure that you're designing your system poorly if doing the above is required. Without seeing the whole thing I can't give you any better suggestions.

Comment: There are many rails engines in the app and we don't want to hardcode engine used in one app. By moving the name to the initializer file we can get away with the code changing when another engine is mounted.                   Tried proc.new and call (without passing in the var thought) before seeing your post and it had some error. Also specifying the jobshop_quotex is equivalent to hardcode the engine name which we are trying to get away with.